# How to forward raw email from django

Tags: python, django, email

So I have a raw email string I'd like to send to another recipient. I'd like to use Django for this (have 3.1 running).

I know I can take my input (say `raw_email`) and make it a python `email.Message` running `email.message_from_string(raw_email)` but from there I'm not sure the best way.

I can imagine I could do something weird like instantiate a new instance of `django.core.mail.EmailMultiAlternatives` and pass each argument 1 by 1 to the constructor, but that seems heavyweight.

FWIW I'm not using SMTP, hence the desire to stick with django code/apis.

Comment: I believe Django's email capability depends on the host running SMTP.

Comment: Well you can plug in any backend to it, so if you want to use [`EmailBackend`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py) then you need SMTP on the host, but in my case I don't.

Specifically I ask too, because Django does seem to rely on some `email` packages, so if I can supply the data in the right format for django classes, it might save some translation headaches.